# How do I append an li and link elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lightbox

I am building a lightbox that I would like to show a list of images when I click on divs with different classes that are specific to certain list of images. The lightbox is working, when I click on divs it appears but the issue arrives when I click on a dive with the class of '.work-1' the list appears as a string instead of the actual pictures. Ive come for help.

```js
    /* Gallery operation*/
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery');
const list = document.createElement('ul');
const lightbox = document.createElement('div');
const parentDiv = document.querySelector('header').parentNode;
const childDiv = document.querySelector('header');
/*const newList =*/
const logo = [
  '<a href="images/logos1.jpg"></a> ',
  '<a href="images/logos2.jpg"></a> ',
  '<a href="images/logos3.jpg"></a> ',
  '<a href="images/logos4.jpg"></a> ',
];
const flyer = [
  '<a href="images/logos1.jpg"></a> ',
  '<a href="images/logos2.jpg"></a> ',
  '<a href="images/logos3.jpg"></a> ',
  '<a href="images/logos4.jpg"></a> ',
];

button.forEach(function getThem(div){
   div.addEventListener('click',function(){
     const box  = parentDiv.insertBefore(lightbox, childDiv);
     box.id = 'lightbox';
     const newBox = box.appendChild(list);
     function getList(){
               if(e.target.className === 'work-1'){
          logo.forEach(function(logo){
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerText = e;
            newBox.append(li);
          });
        }else if(e.target.className === 'work-2'){
            flyer.forEach(function(flyer){
              var li = document.createElement('li');
              li.innerText = e;
              newBox.append(li);
            });
          }
        };
        box.getList();
        box.classList.add('active');
       console.log(button);

   });
   lightbox.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return
  lightbox.classList.remove('active')
});
```

Comment: for one, you are setting your innerText to `e`, which I believe is supposed to be an event, but not exactly sure. I think you want to set the innerText to `logo` or `flyer`

Answer (score 0):

I think your strategie is not quite right, i think what you want to do is show an image

`<img>`

instead of an anchor tag

`<a href'..>`

you can get this result by appending an `<img>` to your li with a `src='images/something.jpg'`

Therefore you want to have a list with all the urls to your image:

```
const logos = [
  'images/logos1.jpg',
  'images/logos2.jpg',
  'images/logos3.jpg',
  'images/logos4.jpg',
]
```

then try adding this:

```
logos.forEach(function(logo){
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = logo;
            li.append(img);
            newBox.append(li);
          });
```

ES6:

```
logo.forEach((logo) => {
   const li = document.createElement('li');

   const img = document.createElement('img');

   img.src = logo; // set the url of your image like 'images/logos1.jpg'

   li.append(img);

   newBox.append(li);
})
```